# vba while loop not working - access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form with a subform below it. The main form has a "overwrite" option where I can type in a value within txtComments and this will then input a value in the subform.comments field only if its check box has a true value (eg. its checked)

As it stands I'm using this code which works only for the select row of data not the entire subform dataset:

(note: I've simplified the names of the fields and values)

```
Private Sub Command118_Click()

    Dim rst As Recordset, i As Integer

    Set rst = Subform.RecordsetClone
    i = 0
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        i = i + 1
        rst.Edit

        If [SubformCheckbox] = True Then
            [SubformComments] = [txtComments]
        Else
            [SubformComments] = 0
        End If

        rst.Update
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used wrong variables. Try this:

```
    If rst![SubformCheckbox] = True Then
        rst![SubformComments] = [txtComments]
    Else
        rst![SubformComments] = 0
    End If
```

If you want to do not touch not checked records, change the loop like this:

```
With rst
    Do While Not .EOF
        If ![SubformCheckbox] = True Then
            .Edit
            ![SubformComments] = [txtComments]
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

For performance improvement you can filter the recordset leaving checked rows only, then update all of them in the loop, but best performance will be reached if you'll use `UPDATE` SQL query for updating the table directly, without using recordset at all.

Comment: One thing though, can I make the Else statement leave existing comment fields alone?

Comment: eg. If it finds a check box row with a true value add the TXTComment form the main form otherwise don't do anything

Comment: If that worked for you, you should check the answer as correct

Comment: sorry about that, checked now :)

Comment: Edited the answer